# Корректная обрезка текста

Tags: php

Есть текст (всегда разный), который содержит html разметку (тоже всегда разную). Необходимо выделять из текста первые два предложения, но таким образом, чтобы html вертка не была нарушена, т.е. чтобы не было разрывов между тегами. Например нельзя разделять так : 
    `<p> ... </p>,`
    `<ol><p></p> ... </ol>`
и т.п. Нужно, чтобы два получившихся фрагмента были независимы друг от друга и могли корректно отображаться в браузере

Comment: В `<p> ... </p>`,  `<ol><p></p> ... </ol>` теги вроде не разбиваются же?

Comment: вот и нужно найти где закрывается открытый тег и продлить предложение до этого тега, включая его самого. Для меня сложность, как определить какой тег должен быть закрывающим

Comment: Как вариант, можно обрабатывать как XML и тягать из него нужные ноды со всеми вложенными. http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.xml.php

Comment: Вот это идея. Попробую

Answer (score 0):

всё очень просто.

```
// берёте текст
$text = '<p>blabla bla</p>test. test2<b>li<ol></b>';
// Викидываете всё лишнее
$text = strip_tags($text);
// бьёте на предложение
$text = explode('.', $text);
// рендерите как вам нужно
echo '<p>'.$text[0].'</p>';
echo '<b>'.$text[1].'</b>';
```

и не стоит брать какую то непонятную разметку по причинам:

1. Это не безопасно
2. Много багов

Comment: Нарушение PSR-2, раздел 4.4. Не подумайте, что специально выискивал, просто увидел и вспомнилось.

Comment: Вся сложность в том, что верстка верная и нужно сохранение всех тегов.

Comment: @IK Не  усложнайте это не к чему, и почему вы так уверены что html 100% валидный?

Comment: @rjhdby спасибо исправил :D

Comment: потому что верстают верстальщики:)

Comment: ну вы представляете что до этого предложения есть ещё какие то элементы.